# X fails to load

Tags: xorg

Today I tried to boot Ubuntu with 9wm (which I had installed before), first by modifying the GRUB boot from 'quiet splash' to 'text', later adding it to LightDM. As it didn't work, I removed the LightDM entry and restored GRUB. But when I try to login with *any* window manager in LightDM, it just stops and opens LightDM again. If I try to run `startx` from a TTY, it shows errors, saying all time that `No protocol specified`. What can I do?

UPDATE: It just happens with my user, logging in with another one works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surprisingly, the workaround for this problem is very simple. Just remove all .Xauthority files in your home folder with this command:

```
rm ~/.Xauthority*
```

Answer (score 0):

If removing ~/.Xauthority doesn't work, you may be out of disk space. I assume it has something to do with not being able to log what it needs to log.

Answer (score 0):

For me work this:

```
cd ~
sudo chmod -R user:user ./
```

where **user** is a user used for login in system.