# Black screen on boot. FailsafeX: "Screen not found"

Tags: gnome, xorg, 13.10

<strike>I made a regular update using update center yesterday on</strike>  My Samsung NP730U3E with Ubuntu gnome 13.10 <strike>and today it</strike> won't start. Or rather: it just gives me a black screen. On start up I get to enter my encryption password and everything seems fine. But after the encryption password is accepted it just blanks out.

When I boot into recovery mode and try to boot failsafeX it returns "Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found (EE)"

After booting into recovery mode and "Resume normal boot" I get to the tty1 prompt. If I head over to "tty7", where the graphical things usually are going on I just see this (and it's frozen):
[image]

What to do?

Comment: Have you tried tty1 and startx?

Comment: It gave me a bunch of errors that I kind of understood! :D There was a parse error in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. And modified that file not too long ago, trying to configure touchégg correctly.
I will look into this and will return when I've got things sorted out.

Comment: Yup. I deleted everything (which was the touchégg configs) from the xorg.conf file, and now everything is working great. Thank you! :)

Comment: I'm so glad I could help. If you have more problems you can come to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Novine's comment on my question indirectly gave me the answer. When I booted into recovery mode, went on by "resume normal boot" and then logged in via tty1 I ran `startx`. This gave me an error saying there was a parse error in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. I then opened up that file and emptied that file from some unnecessary lines I had put in there a short while ago (I saved it all empty).

That made the trick, and everything is now working great! Big thanks to Novine! :)

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem today on Lenovo P50. The issue was that I switching to nvidia driver from stock open source driver. The display would go black when I boot and login gets stuck in loop when I go to recovery mode. When doing Ctrl+Alt+F1 and trying to startx I saw errors such as screen not found. The solution was simply to roll back to stock drives using this command line:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

Voila! I'm back in but then xorg reported some error. So I did,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

Now there are no issues.

Refrences:

- [How do you remove Nvidia's proprietary drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/a/407322/512372)
- [startx doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143179/startx-doesnt-work)
- [X fails to load](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162334/x-fails-to-load)
- [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)