# How can I fix an Ubuntu partition that gets stuck on the motherboard splash screen?

Tags: updates, boot-repair

I have Ubuntu 20.04 and recently did an update with `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade`. Since then, once I select Ubuntu from the GRUB loader, the machine gets stuck on the motherboard splash screen (Aorus). I've tried going into advanced mode alternate kernels and repairing packages, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Solved thanks to this answer by Shital Shah: https://askubuntu.com/a/755688/1034279

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Black screen on boot. FailsafeX: "Screen not found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/371484/black-screen-on-boot-failsafex-screen-not-found)